# Running multiple if statements at once PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to print the quantity chosen from a table to another page. I have a series of if statements for this to show if a quantity has been inputted and if it has then it will display the quantity and the item.

The problem is that it is only running the first if statement and ignoring the rest of them. If anyone knows how I could run them all it would be a great help!

```
<?php

  if(!empty($_POST['qtybang']))
  {
    echo $qtybang.' Bang Bang Chicken<br>';
  }

  if(!empty($_POST['$qtyFlatbread']))
  {
    echo $qtyFlatbread.' Flatbread<br>';
  }

  if(!empty($_POST['$qtyMexican']))
  {
  echo $qtyMexican.' Mexican Bean Stew<br>';
  }

  if(!empty($_POST['$qtyrice']))
  {
  echo $qtyrice.' Rice Bowl<br>';
  }

  if(!empty($_POST['$qtySandwiche']))
  {
  echo $qtySandwiche.' sandwiches<br>';
  }


  if(!empty($_POST['$qtyCapachino']))
  {
  echo $qtyCapachino.' Capachino<br>';
  }


  if(!empty($_POST['$qtyAmericano']))
  {      
  echo $qtyAmericano.' Americano<br>';
  }


  if(!empty($_POST['$qtyExpresso']))
  {
  echo $qtyExpresso.' Expresso<br>';
  }?>
```

[Order Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfGka.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwFms.png)

Comment: It won't be "ignoring" anything. Are you sure the post variable names are correct? `$_POST['$qtyFlatbread']` - you have a dollar sign at the beginning...

Comment: Are you sure your post variable has `$` in them? `$qtyAmericano` should be `qtyAmericano` I think!

Comment: Why is there a $ sign on all other variables except the 1st one? Maybe that is why the first if is returning true.

Comment: it should be like `echo $_POST['qtybang'].' Bang Bang Chicken<br>';`

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes thank you everyone have it working!!

Answer (score 1):

The if statements are actually processed but simply the checked vars are empty, thats why you have no output.
It was because the `$` in the $_POST list are placed wrong on all instances except the first condition.

```
    <?php
     $_POST['qtybang'] = 'something';
     $qtybang = $_POST['qtybang'];
     $_POST['$qtyFlatbread'] = 'something';
     $qtyFlatbread = $_POST['$qtyFlatbread'];

     if(!empty($_POST['qtybang']))
     {
       echo $qtybang.' Bang Bang Chicken<br>'."\n";
     }

     if(!empty($_POST['$qtyFlatbread']))
     {
       echo $qtyFlatbread.' Flatbread<br>'."\n";
     }

     if(!empty($_POST['$qtyMexican']))
     {
       echo $qtyMexican.' Mexican Bean Stew<br>'."\n";
     }

     if(!empty($_POST['$qtyrice']))
     {
       echo $qtyrice.' Rice Bowl<br>'."\n";
     }

     if(!empty($_POST['$qtySandwiche']))
     {
       echo $qtySandwiche.' sandwiches<br>'."\n";
     }


     if(!empty($_POST['$qtyCapachino']))
     {
      echo $qtyCapachino.' Capachino<br>'."\n";
     }


     if(!empty($_POST['$qtyAmericano']))
     {      
       echo $qtyAmericano.' Americano<br>'."\n";
     }


     if(!empty($_POST['$qtyExpresso']))
     {
       echo $qtyExpresso.' Expresso<br>'."\n";
     }
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the edit, `Ctrl+K` doesnt do the job any more, although it did the last days